# How to make checkbox 'C' FALSE, if checkbox 'A' and checkbox 'B' is FALSE

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript

I want to make checkbox 'C' FALSE, if i changed the checkbox 'A' and checkbox 'B' from TRUE to FALSE.

Here's my sample code, dunno what to add to continue.

I still want checkbox 'C' to remain TRUE, IF checkbox 'A' OR 'B' is TRUE.

Thanks!

```js
$(".loyalty").change(function () {
    if ($(".loyalty").is(':checked')) {
        $(".email_optin_status").prop('checked', true);
    } 
    else {
        $(".email_optin_status").prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$(".newsletters").change(function () {
    if ($(".newsletters").is(':checked')) {
        $(".email_optin_status").prop('checked', true);
    } 
    else {
        $(".email_optin_status").prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="loyalty" name="A"> A
<hr>
<input type="checkbox" class="newsletters" name="B"> B
<hr>
<input type="checkbox" class="email_optin_status" name="C"> C
```

Comment: Hope the answer I posted helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".loyalty").change(function () {
    if ($(".loyalty").is(':checked')) {
        $(".email_optin_status").prop('checked', true);
    } 
    else if ($(".newsletters").is(':checked')) {
        $(".email_optin_status").prop('checked', true);
    } else
    {
        $(".email_optin_status").prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$(".newsletters").change(function () {
    if ($(".newsletters").is(':checked')) {
        $(".email_optin_status").prop('checked', true);
    } 
    else if(($(".loyalty").is(':checked'))){
        $(".email_optin_status").prop('checked', true);
    }
else{
        $(".email_optin_status").prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="loyalty" name="A"> A
<hr>
<input type="checkbox" class="newsletters" name="B"> B
<hr>
<input type="checkbox" class="email_optin_status" name="C"> C
```

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The logic is pretty simple:

```
C.checked = A.checked || B.checked;
```

e.g.

```js
function updateCBs(evt) {
  document.querySelector('[name="C"]').checked =
    document.querySelector('[name="A"]').checked ||
    document.querySelector('[name="B"]').checked;
}

// Add listeners onload
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var cbs = [
    document.querySelector('[name="A"]'),
    document.querySelector('[name="B"]')
  ];
  cbs.forEach(cb => cb.addEventListener('click', updateCBs, false));

  // Update checkboxes
  updateCBs();
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="A"> A<hr>
<input type="checkbox" name="B"> B<hr>
<input type="checkbox" name="C"> C
```

The listener could be one line, but it's a long statement.